# TPM - Put my own private & public key inside the tpm

Tags: encryption, tpm, bitlocker

In the TPM I can generate an SRK (Storage Root Key) that will be stored on the chip. This key will be used to wrap and protect other keys (not stored on the TPM).

Let's say I don't trust the chip in the key generation process, is there any way to put my own SRK in the TPM? Same question for the wrapped keys?

There are command TPM_CC_Import and TPM_CC_Load, but the first seems to be able to onnly import symetric keys (and I want to import an asymetric one) and the second seems to only be able to load an object created by the TPM.

Anyone has any idea or somethink to help me?